# What's missing from this simple recipe that creates a user?

Tags: chef, linux

I've spun many boxes in the cloud before, but was growing tired of going through the same dance; and as I'm trying to get familiar with Chef, I figured, that's a good use case to do a little learning.

Ah, that feeling when you think you know how it'll work - but it doesn't. Since I'm new to Chef, I suspect I'm not doing something right in this recipe, which is like my 2nd ever. NOTE: I understand there probably are 'cookbooks' out there that do something like that, but at this point I'm trying to build some ver basic knowledge with the simplest approach.

```
user 'foox' do
  comment 'test me'
  uid '6711'
  home '/home/foox'
  shell '/bin/bash'
  password '<password_shadow_here>'
end

directory "/home/foox" do
  owner "foox"
  group "foox"
  mode 00755
  action :create
end

directory "/home/foox/.ssh" do
  owner "foox"
  group "foox"
  mode 00600
  action :create
end

file '/home/foox/.ssh/authorized_keys' do
  owner "foox"
  group "foox"
  mode "00600"
  content IO.read('/root/.ssh/authorized_keys')
  action :create
end
```

Now, this does create the user with a password and home folder with .ssh, and copies the public key from root's own file. But this system ends up failing to let me log in -- `Permission denied (publickey)` -- when using the same private key as what I have as my root's. But, well, root user wasn't created by my recipe. And if I create my own user manually, it's working fine.

I guess there's something missing in my recipe, then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll put in an answer although I'm not 100% sure. I think that you got the permissions wrong on `~/.ssh` and it should be `0700` instead of `0600`, otherwise the user cannot access it.

Another tip which is unrelated to your problem, the `user` resource has a property `manage_home` (https://docs.chef.io/resource_user.html#properties) which will create the home directory for you and will you save a redundant resource.

Comment: you were correct! and thanks for the tip! - so that's what I was missing

Comment: @alexakarpov and a small point avoid using numeric modes in chef recipes, this has the potential to break in very surprising ways when you set directory modes as starting with a 0 you're defining an octal number and not what you're likely after.You should declare them as string like `mode '0600'` to avoid that.